# Where does the energy go when two drops combine?

Tags: energy-conservation, fluid-statics, surface-tension

Recently been studying fluid mechanics and I have a query in context with surface energy.

I am aware that energy is decreased when two drops combine, But not aware of where that energy goes.

Does the temperature of the combined drop increase or is it radiated to the surroundings?

Follow-up question, If it is the first one does that mean after it rains the temperature of the ocean is increased ever so slightly?

Comment: heat is both radiated and absorbed

Comment: This is a weak phenomenon, hence obviously heat released should be less

Comment: @PranavAggarwal K awesome, you certain? Just a bit skeptical sorry.

Comment: I am sure as you cannot find any other way to lose the energy with a very low magnitude.

Comment: for this phenomenon

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Initially the energy goes into accelerating the fluid, turning into kinetic energy. If there are interfaces nearby [like a superhydrophobic surface this can make the droplet propel itself away from it](https://dukespace.lib.duke.edu/dspace/bitstream/10161/9972/1/Liu_duke_0066D_12995.pdf), but with low efficiency: most energy goes into wobbling that presumably emits some acoustic waves but mostly heats the fluid as the viscosity dampens the oscillations.

[For microcopic droplets one can simulate the molecular interactions](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/acs.jpcc.8b06507OHD6o) and it looks like energy proportionally goes into making more hydrogen bonds, but the rest increases the temperature-entropy term.

Comment: Really cool! Just to clarify, Is any energy converted in the form of heat?

Comment: Looks like it - whenever there is dissipation like viscosity or friction motion turns into heat eventually.

Comment: The last link is not working.